# Why might parted mklabel not work?

Tags: partitioning

I've just got a new ssd card which I'm trying to partition. I have already used it and I know it is in a good condition, still I've had a lot of trouble, and it has come to using parted to try and fix it:

```
parted /dev/sdb
```

then

```
(parted) print all
/dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
(parted) mklabel gpt
(parted) print all
/dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
(parted) mklabel msdos
(parted) print all
/dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
```

and so on...

What might be the solution to this? I really don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Maybe you need to run a dd first to the first sectors ? I assume you don't have any files there (because you want to create a new partition table). Try `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1000` to write with zeros the first 512kB. Then try again with `parted`.

Comment: @NikTh That sounds like it would have worked, but I had to give up. Thanks though.